# How to fix a type error for non iterabble socket object

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to set up a chatroom in python and right now I am trying to set up user names and passwords but when I try to send the data through a dictionary for loop I get the type error for socket objects

class Server:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# just a list of connections
connection = {

}
def n_remover(user):
    with open("UserPass.txt" , 'r') as f:
        passuser = f.readlines()
        for x in passuser:
            print(x)
            for area, value in enumerate(x):
                print(value, area)
                if value == '\n':
                    print(value,area)
                    passuser[passuser.index(x)] = passuser[passuser.index(x)][0:area]
                    print(passuser[0])
        return passuser[passuser.index(user)]

def file_len(file):
    with open('UserPass.txt', 'r') as f:
        for length, value in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return length+1

# this bind the server to any ip in ipv4 and any port above 10000
def __init__(self):
        self.sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 10000))
        self.sock.listen(1)

# this handles sending out data to all of the users and handels the disconnect of a user the a arg is a ip and port. and c is the threaded connection.
def handler(self, c, a):
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        print(str(data)[0:1])
        if str(data)[0:1] == "/p":
            datasplit = (str(self.data)).split(" ")
            password_name = [self.datasplit[1] + ' ' + self.datasplit[2]]
            with open("UserPass.txt" , 'r+') as f:
                passuser = n_remover(password_name)
                for key, value in connection:
                    if c == key:
                        self.connection[c] = self.datasplit[1]
        else:
            print(self.connection)

            try:
                l = self.connection[c]

            except IndexError:
                self.connection[c] = "anon"

            for key,value in self.connection:
                key.send(bytes(self.connection[c] + ': ' + data))

            if not data:
                print(str(a[0]) + ':' + str(a[1], "disconnected"))
                del self.connection[c]
                c.close
                break
```

What I expect it to do is just iterate through the dictonary and send the data to the socket keys stored but instead it gives
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\undea\Desktop\Chatroom\Chatroom.py", line 72, in handler
    for key,value in self.connection:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable socket object

Comment: Please post a proper MCVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for key,value in self.connection:
    key.send(bytes(self.connection[c] + ': ' + data))
```

Isn't self.connection a list at this point of time?
What is in self.connection at this point? a dict? If yes what is in it?

Looks like python can't unpack the content to key, value because the content can't be splitted in two values.

It seems like you are trying to split a socket object into key and value.